# How to sync multiple *.gitignore files to .gitignore_global?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'd like my `.gitignore_global` to be the head node of several `*.gitignore` files. To achieve this, I'd like `.gitignore_global` to append contents of multiple `*.gitignore` files to itself by importing `*.gitignore` files with its path.

For example, if `git` understands `source` command, `.gitignore_global` may look like:

```
# platform-specific .gitignore files
source ~/.gitignore/gitignore.git/Global/Linux.gitignore
source ~/.gitignore/gitignore.git/Global/OSX.gitignore
source ~/.gitignore/gitignore.git/Global/Windows.gitignore

# language-specific .gitignore files
source ~/.gitignore/gitignore.git/C++.gitignore
source ~/.gitignore/gitignore.git/Java.gitignore

# above .gitignore files are cloned from the following Github page:
# https://github.com/github/gitignore.git
```

Unfortunately, the `source` command was not recognized by `git`. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command `source` is not really a command, but shell built-in. It is designed to process shell scripts within original shell process (without executing new process).

Command `source` cannot source anything but actual shell scripts. So, your attempt to source `.gitignore*` files is not going to work, not by any stretch of imagination.

`.gitignore` mechanism is very simple, you can simply concatenate all your gitignore files and that should work. However, it is not really advisable. Correct solution is to apply gitignore on as needed basis.

You can find very good source for common gitgnore rules at http://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: I understand `source` won't work here. How would you import contents of `.gitignore` files into `.gitignore_global` then?

Comment: Concatenate by using commands like `cat $filename >> .gitignore_global`? And loop it with different filenames?

Comment: yes. But be warned - really big gitignore file can slow git operations, because git will have to check ALL rules you put there

Answer (score 0):

As @mvp mentions, more rules can slow processing. Although the fstat is typically far more painful than the ignore rules overhead on repos with lots of files. Particularly noticeable if you use `__git_ps1` in PS1 command prompt - git commands start feeling sluggish.

Meanwhile, importing separate .gitignore_XXX files on the fly each time would generally be unnecessary overhead. However, once setup, gitignore files tend to change infrequently. So benefit is mostly for organizational purposes (which *is* nice, true, but a convenience we can probably live without).

Consider keeping gitignore_global fairly lightweight and using local/project-level .gitingore for the heavier, more detailed, ignore patterns.

Reminder: `git check-ignore -v SomeFileOrPath` is extremely helpful when encounter cases of "why is that file being ignored".

Also, I find the following site to be useful for quickly generating hybrid gitignore files when I start a new project / git repo:

```
https://www.gitignore.io
```

Example: Xcode + c++ + gradle + java + ruby + libreoffice + osx + svn + vim

It even places them in alphabetical order :)